# How to calculate the "rest value" of a plot?

Tags: matlab

Didn't know how to paraphrase the question well.

Function for example:
[image]

Data:https://www.dropbox.com/s/wr61qyhhf6ujvny/data.mat?dl=0

In this case how do I calculate that the rest point of this function is ~1? I have access to the vector that makes the plot.
I guess the mean is an approximation but in some cases it can be pretty bad.

Comment: Can you provide the original data too?  Also, what exactly do you want?  Do you want to determine the best `x` value that results in `y` being equal to 1?  There are also multiple values that map to `y ~ 1`.

Comment: @rayryeng I want to reach the conclusion that the rest value of this function is approximately 1.

Comment: By "rest point" do you mean steady state?  You can also compute a histogram of data and determine the bin with the highest count.  Then again, I can't tell you if it's right unless I have access to that data.  Please update your post with access to this data.  An image is insufficient for reproducing your results.

Comment: I only have access to the values not the function. Do you want me to upload a .mat file with it?

Comment: The data is fine.  Anything we can use to reproduce your results.

Comment: I think steady state might be what I'm looking for

Comment: @AntonioCraveiro - That's fine.  I'm writing an answer, but I'd like to verify my code by your data.

Comment: @rayryeng added a link with the .mat file

Comment: Cheers.  Let me verify

Comment: rayryeng provides a solution that finds the median, similar to your original idea of finding the mean.  However, the median/mode/mean may not correspond to the "rest value", depending on what you mean.  For example, consider a saw-tooth wave that eventually flat lines to something other than the mean.  I think a better solution would find the points to zero or small derivatives.  You can use `diff(y) ./ diff(x)` to get an estimate of the derivative.

Comment: @JeffIrwin - That's a better way to go, but I did mention that I assumed that the majority of the data hovers around the "rest value".  If that's the case, the median should work OK.... but if the data is anything else but, finding points with small derivatives should work great.

Comment: @JeffIrwin played a bit with that, it works and makes sense that it would be good for more complex functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption that the "rest" point is the steady-state value in your data and the fact that the steady-state value happens the majority of the times in your data, you can simply bin all of the points and use each unique value as a separate bin.  The bin with the highest count should correspond to the steady-state value.

You can do this by a combination of [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) and [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html).  Assuming your data is stored in `y`, do this:

```
%// Find all unique values in your data
bins = unique(y);

%// Find the total number of occurrences per unique value
counts = histc(y, bins);

%// Figure out which bin has the largest count
[~,max_bin] = max(counts);

%// Figure out the corresponding y value
ss_value = bins(max_bin);
```

`ss_value` contains the steady-state value of your data, corresponding to the most occurring output point with the assumptions I laid out above.

A minor caveat with the above approach is that this is not friendly to floating point data whose unique values are generated by floating point values whose decimal values beyond the first few significant digits are different.

Here's an example of your data from point 2300 to 2320:

```
>> format long g;
>> y(2300:2320)

ans =

          0.99995724232555
         0.999957488454868
         0.999957733165346
         0.999957976465197
         0.999958218362579
         0.999958458865564
         0.999958697982251
         0.999958935720613
         0.999959172088623
         0.999959407094224
         0.999959640745246
         0.999959873049548
         0.999960104014889
         0.999960333649014
         0.999960561959611
         0.999960788954326
          0.99996101464076
         0.999961239026462
         0.999961462118947
         0.999961683925704
         0.999961904454139
```

Therefore, what I'd recommend is to perhaps round so that the first 5 or so significant digits are maintained.

You can do this to your dataset before you continue:

```
num_digits = 5;
y_round = round(y*(10^num_digits))/(10^num_digits);
```

This will first multiply by `10^n` where `n` is the number of digits you desire so that the decimal point is shifted over by `n` positions.  We round this result, then divide by `10^n` to bring it back to the scale that it was before.  If you do this, for those points that were 0.9999... where there are `n` decimal places, these will get rounded to 1, and it may help in the above calculations.

However, more recent versions of MATLAB have this functionality already built-in to `round`, and you can just do this:

```
num_digits = 5;
y_round = round(y,num_digits);
```

## Minor Note

More recent versions of MATLAB discourage the use of `histc` and recommend you use [`histcounts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) instead.  Same function definition and expected inputs and outputs... so just replace `histc` with `histcounts` if your MATLAB version can handle it.

---

Using the above logic, you could also use the median too.  If the majority of data is fluctuating around 1, then the median would have a high probability that the steady-state value is chosen... so try this too:

```
ss_value = median(y_round);
```

Comment: Isn't this just the median though?

Comment: @AntonioCraveiro - I suppose you're right!  I wanted to write something that could generalize to arbitrary signals.

Comment: @AntonioCraveiro - I've edited the post to include the median as well.  Seems like a good fit for your data... but try both and see how it goes.

Comment: @AntonioCraveiro - I've added some more information on how to to deal with floating point precision of data.  If you check your data out, a lot of the points are 0.9999.... which will wreck havoc if you decide to use the median or use the counts method that I created above.  Check it out.